# Dark Flair Missing Image

Tags: support, flair

Although I see this has happened from time to time before, I noticed that the dark themed flair is missing it's image currently.

[image]

I just wanted to make sure that someone is aware and I haven't seen any recent reports of this bug here.

**Update:**

I'm seeing this from the UK, England and I am seeing it missing on multiple devices and on different networks and different service providers (missing on the flair page as well as my website [www.rudikershaw.com](http://www.rudikershaw.com)). I have cleared my cache, so I am assuming that this is an issue with the specific node servicing the image requests in my area.

Comment: On my flair page, I see it fine, but I have a default gravatar, so perhaps that matters.

Comment: @Joe - I also see it missing from my website [www.rudikershaw.com](http://www.rudikershaw.com). I've tried various browsers, mobile devices, etc. Although all from inside the same network.

Comment: It seems to be happing to me now as well. http://www.shobhitpuri.com at the footer.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I can see the image on your site. If it's anything like the issue I experienced it should sort itself out within a day or so. It's entirely possible is an eventual consistency issue of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it's missing to me.  From your website (which I certainly don't have cached):

[image: Screenshot]

It's also fine on the SO page.  So either it's fixed now and you have a cache issue, or it's something specific to you.

Comment: Well, as long as it's not missing for visitors I actually don't mind. Although I refreshed my cache and it's still missing. Could be a clustering issue, if there were say an issue with a single node generating the images.

Comment: Indeed.  US Midwest, if relevant.

Comment: Just checked it from outside my network and service provider using 4G and it's still missing. Must be area related. In the UK, England.

Comment: @RudiKershaw I don't see it either. UK, EE, 3G (H+) tethered connection.

Comment: Now that it genuinely does seem to be fixed, I'll select this as the answer! (At least I hope that it is. Can't really be sure.)